# How do I get my user info to save to the database from the Signup form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I trying to authentication from scratch in rails 5 and my user information is not being saved when entered into the signup form. I also receive this rails error: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

@user = User.new(params[:user])

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

attr_accessor :password
before_save :encrypt_password

validates_confirmation_of :password
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
validates_presence_of :email
validates_uniqueness_of :email

def self.authenticate(email, password)
user = find_by_email(email)
if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, 
user.password_salt)
user
else
nil
end
end

def encrypt_password
if password.present?
  self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, 
password_salt)
end
end
end



<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<div class="error_messages">
<h2>Form is invalid</h2>
<ul>
<% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
<li><%= message %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<p>
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</p>
<p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>



class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
@user = User.new
end

def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
else
render "new"
end
end
end


class Post < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_password
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you create from scratch make sure for each controller you have strong parameter declaration, let me explain, inside create method you put User.new(user_params), user_params is another method that we put usually on bottom of class, we put the method def user_params, this we declare what allowed field / data that can be passed to our model since you using bcrypt gem, I think the field is same as below

additional info most of rails user using [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authorization user

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :salt, :encrypted_password)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So new to rails and trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: if it help and correct your problem can you accept my answer by checking mark beside my answer so this question marked solved

Comment: This helped but I also needed to remove attr_accessor. Thanks again :)

Comment: yes in rails >=4 you declare strong parameters as I wrote above, this replace attr_attributes (read,write,accessor) for fields that usually use in rails 3